# ios RestKit getting certain number of elements instead of full list

Tags: ios, iphone, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I need to load objects in tens those provided in json data instead of all objects. I am aiming to implement an app like twitter. In other words, when user taps "load more" button in uitableview, restkit will load next ten objects if json data has. I couldn't find any example nor a restkit method about this. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: this is something you implement in the backend, RestKit cannot help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the purpose of the `RKPaginator` class. Check the docs [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKPaginator.html) for a description and sample code. It ties in with all of the usual mappings and response descriptors to enable paginated download management.